# Is it better to parse an XML at program startup, or as needed by method calls?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I'm creating a game right now in C# that uses XML to build the skills of different characters. (This file contains attributes, such as damage, that have been stripped in this example for brevity's sake.)

```
<Classes>
    <Class name="Mage">
        <skill name="Fireball">
        </skill>
    </Class>
    <Class name="Knight">
        <skill name="Slash">
        </skill>
    </Class>
    .
    .
    .
</Classes>
```

I'm creating an XMLParser class to grab the skills for each character based on their name ('XMLParser.getSkillsByName("Mage")' returns a list of skills).

Should this XML file be parsed at the startup of the game and each set of skills assigned to the corresponding class type (Mage, Knight, etc.); or should the parser be called on a need-to-know-basis? i.e. Once a player chooses their class type, the constructor for that class choice will parse the XML file for the skills that are associated with it.

Currently, I've started implementing the latter choice. Each class type has a base type of 'Player'. Player has a method to get the skills for a class type based on its name--so in the constructor of each character, there would be a line similar to

```
List<Skill> mySkills = base.getSkillsByName("Mage");
```

I'm only asking because the place where I work is doing something similar, but they parse the XML at the very start and then call from the list of objects based on what they need from it.

Comment: It depends on your use-case. If it's a huge `XML` file and you know you only need one set of properties from it (could be a different set each time the programme is run) then you may-as-well just parse it on-demand. But if you are going to be bouncing around the file a lot, parse it once-and-done.

Comment: Whether you create the objects at startup or generate them later depends on how you want to handle the memory management of the objects.  As an aside, are you using the XMLSerializer class to serialize/deserialize your XML objects?

Comment: @EBrown That makes sense. I'm worried about issues similar to what John Wu mentioned below though.

Comment: @maniak1982 I'm using XMLTextReader. I'm not too huge on what the "best XML parsing practice" might be, so any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: @ZachCleaver There are mutiliple ways to parse `XML`, the `XmlTextReader`, LINQ to XML, `XmlSerializer`, etc. The way you choose tends to depend on the *strictness* of your data. I.e. does the layout change often, are new *properties* (not actual data-objects) added often, etc. If your layout is very strict (not often changing), then I recommend you read of [XmlSerializer on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both techniques are viable but in your case I would choose to parse at load time.  That way your game will have slightly better performance during play time, and you eliminate the risk of running into data validation errors in the middle of a game.